# Hyper-V required for testing Windows Phone 8 App on actual device

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hyper-v

Is Hyper-V still required for testing a WP8 app when you test on actual device?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need Hyper-V to test on a physical device.